# How does reviewing work?

Tags: support

I'm unclear how to "review" a new user post (at https://fitness.stackexchange.com/review). The instructions say `Please review these posts and vote, comment, or flag them appropriately.`

How can I mark that I think the answer is acceptable and in the spirit of StackExchange without voting on it (i.e. I don't agree with the content of the answer, but it does not require moderator attention orrewording)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just leave it and move on to the next post - it is not intended to be solely a list of things that need moderator attention.